# Vuetify combobox not creating new object on Enter

Tags: vue.js, combobox, vuetify.js

Using Vuetify, I'm unable to create new objects via the combobox when pressing enter even when using the exact markup and data configuration provided in the docs. In a JSFiddle, it functions as expected when using the same Vue and Vuetify versions which leads me to think that it's something in my project causing the issue but I cannot figure out what that might be... Any ideas?

EDIT: Using Vue 2.6.10 and Vuetify 2.3.2

```
<v-combobox
v-model="select"
:items="items"
label="Select a favorite activity or create a new one"
multiple
auto-select-first
>
</v-combobox>
```

```
<script>
export default {
     data: function() {
          return {
           select: ['Vuetify', 'Programming'],
           items: ['Programming', 'Design','Vue','Vuetify']
          }
     }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that occurs when passing the `auto-select-first` prop on the component. Bug has been reported and the issue may be tracked here: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/11790